# Email url scheme For Android

Tags: android

I create button that use "mailto" to send email via email applications,when i click on the button it shows 2 option(gmail,outlook). Is there a possible way to show only the outlook application?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a possible way. You need to get package manager first. And iterate over the list of available matches that is received via queryIntentActivities() method. And find the app by passing package name of that outlook app. Code is below.

```
Intent outlookIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    outlookIntent.setType("text/html");

    final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    final List<ResolveInfo> matches = pm.queryIntentActivities(outlookIntent, 0);
    String outlookActivityClass = null;

    for (final ResolveInfo info : matches) {
        if (info.activityInfo.packageName.equals("com.microsoft.office.outlook")) {
            outlookActivityClass = info.activityInfo.name;
            if (outlookActivityClass != null && !outlookActivityClass.isEmpty()) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    outlookIntent.setClassName("com.microsoft.office.outlook", outlookActivityClass);
    outlookIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "yourmail@gmail.com" });
    outlookIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
    outlookIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, "cc@gmail.com"); // if necessary
    outlookIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Email message");
    outlookIntent.setData(Uri.parse("yourmail@gmail.com"));
    startActivity(outlookIntent);
```

Hope this will help you out.

Comment: can't do that with javascript?

Comment: @ysf15 why do you need you use javascript? are you not working native app?

Comment: no iam not working on native app,i am using Microsoft Dynamics CRM